# Using a trait name as a logger name

Tags: scala, logging, slf4j

I have following code:

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
trait Logger {
    lazy val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass.getName)
}

trait DoSomething1 extends Logger { ... }
trait DoSomething2 extends Logger { ... }
trait DoSomething3 extends Logger { ... }
...
trait DoAll extends DoSomething1 with DoSomething2 with ...

val act = new DoAll {}
```

In my logs I see:

```
INFO  Main$$anon$1: blablabla ...
INFO  Main$$anon$1: blablabla ...
INFO  Main$$anon$1: blablabla ...
ERROR Main$$anon$1: blablabla ...
DEBUG Main$$anon$1: blablabla ...
```

I cannot realize which trait print each message. 
I want to see something like:

```
INFO  Main$$DoSomething1$1: blablabla ...
INFO  Main$$DoSomething3$1: blablabla ...
DEBUG Main$$DoSomething2$1: blablabla ...
```

Or maybe Scala source names:

```
INFO  Main$$DoSomething1.scala$1: blablabla ...
INFO  Main$$DoSomething3.scala$1: blablabla ...
DEBUG Main$$DoSomething2.scala$1: blablabla ...
```

Can I use a trait name as a logger name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Main$$anon$1` is the "java compatible" name of your anonymous compiled scala class `new DoAll {}`. 
It's the same for all traits, because `getClass.getName` return the same value.

If you want to have different values you should override `logger` in each trait, 
and instead of class name use some predefine values while constructing it.

For example you can use following code:

```
trait Logger {
    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggerName)
    def loggerName = getClass.getName
}

trait A {
    def loggerName = "A"
    // ...
}

trait B {
    def loggerName = "B"
    // ...
}
```

etc ...

Comment: It's a good answer. But how can I do this without an explicit loggerName?

Answer (score 0):

A simple pattern that you can use is to mix `Logger` into a companion object and import it:

```
object DoSomething1 extends Logger
trait DoSomething1 {
   import DoSomething1._
   ...
}
object DoSomething2 extends Logger
trait DoSomething2 {
   import DoSomething2._
   ...
}
object DoSomething3 extends Logger
trait DoSomething3 {
   import DoSomething3._
   ...
}
trait DoAll extends DoSomething1 with DoSomething2 with ...

val act = new DoAll {}
```

You should then have something along the lines of:

```
INFO  DoSomething1$: blablabla ...
INFO  DoSomething3$: blablabla ...
DEBUG  DoSomething2$: blablabla ...
```